# knockout.js unwrapObservable function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I find todomvc examples - http://todomvc.com/
When i watch knockout version i find this code (in https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/knockoutjs/js/app.js):

```
// wrapper to hasFocus that also selects text and applies focus async
ko.bindingHandlers.selectAndFocus = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.hasFocus.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext);
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'focus', function () {
            element.focus();
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); // for dependency
        // ensure that element is visible before trying to focus
        setTimeout(function () {
            ko.bindingHandlers.hasFocus.update(element, valueAccessor);
        }, 0);
    }
};
```

I know what do ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); function, but what it do in this code? 
We don't use returned value.

Answer (score 1):

Knockout set up a dependency chain base on what observable you used in current iteration.

To make your update function be executed again when a observable `A` changed, you need to directly or indirectly access to `A`.

Say, if your bindHandlers use the following syntax:

```html
<div data-bind="selectAndFocus: A"></div>
```

you need to use one of the following js code:

```js
valueAccessor();  // directly access
ko.utils.unwrapObservable( valueAccessor ); // directly access
```

If your bindHandler use the following syntax:

```html
<div data-bind="selectAndFocus: { arg0: A, arg1: B }"></div>
```

You need to use the following js to make update handler depends on `A`

```js
// no dependency injection in this line
var va = valueAccessor();  

// directly access
va.arg0();  
ko.utils.unwrapObservable( va.arg0 );
```

See [How dependency tracking works](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#how-dependency-tracking-works) for detailed information.

Comment: I tnick you mean abount this - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#how-dependency-tracking-works?

Comment: Yes, this one is better! Replace the original link.

Answer (score 0):

Knockout sets up publish-subscribe dependencies for observables evaluated in bindings, so that the bindings can update if the observable changes. The code is just using unwrapObservable as a safe way to evaluate the valueAccessor passed to the binding, capturing the dependency.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i dont know that update function executes only if we get access to valueAccessor()() (if i correctly understand)